# Calling Web API not working the first time in Blazor server side app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

When I launch my ASP.Net Core Blazor Server Side app, the first time I click the Save button, nothing happens. The post to the controller/API fires but the PostListing function in my controller/API never gets called. However if  I click the Save button a second time right after, it works as expected. What's going on? Thank you to anyone who can help.

Here's my page:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using SellEverywhere.Data
@using SellEverywhere.Models
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@inject HttpClient Http


<h1>Your Listings</h1>

<table width="100%" style="background:#05163D;color:honeydew">
    <tr>
        <td width="20"> </td>
        <td>
            <h2> Add New Listing Details</h2>
        </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td align="right">
            <button class="btn btn-info" @onclick="AddNewListing">Add New Listing</button>
        </td>
        <td width="10"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<form>
    <table class="form-group">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">ID</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@lsts.Id" readonly />
            </td>
            <td width="20"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Title</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@lsts.Title" />
            </td>
            <td width="20"> </td>
            <td>
                <label for="Description" class="control-label">Description</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@lsts.Description" />
            </td>
            <td width="20"> </td>
            <td>
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Brand</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@lsts.Brand" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Size</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@lsts.Size" />
            </td>
            <td width="20"> </td>
            <td>
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Color</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@lsts.Color" />
            </td>
            <td width="20"> </td>
            <td>
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Condition</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" @bind="@lsts.Condition" />
            </td>
            <td width="20"> </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="(async () => await AddListing())" style="width:220px;">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<table width="100%" style="background:#0A2464;color:honeydew">
    <tr>
        <td width="20"> </td>
        <td>
            <h2>Listing Details</h2>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

@if (listing == null)
{
    <p><em>No listing found...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Condition</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Tag1</th>
                <th>Tag2</th>
                <th>Tag3</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Lowest Price</th>
                <th>Shipping Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var lst in listing)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@lst.Id</td>
                <td>@lst.Title</td>
                <td>@lst.Brand</td>
                <td>@lst.Color</td>
                <td>@lst.Condition</td>
                <td>@lst.Size</td>
                <td>@lst.Description</td>
                <td>@lst.Tag1</td>
                <td>@lst.Tag2</td>
                <td>@lst.Tag3</td>
                <td>@lst.Price</td>
                <td>@lst.LowestPrice</td>
                <td>@lst.ShippingPrice</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@(async () => await EditListing(@lst.Id))" style="width:110px;">Edit</button></td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(async () => await DeleteListing(@lst.Id))">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    Listing[] listing;
    Listing lsts = new Listing();
    string ids = "0";
    //bool showAddrow = false;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        listing = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Listing[]>("https://localhost:44324/api/Listings/");
    }

    void AddNewListing()
    {
        lsts = new Listing();
    }
    // Add New Listings Details Method
    protected async Task AddListing()
    {
        if (lsts.Id == 0)

        {
            await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:44324/api/Listings/", lsts);
        }
        else
        {
            await Http.PutAsJsonAsync("https://localhost:44324/api/Listings/" + lsts.Id, lsts);
        }
        lsts = new Listing();
        listing = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Listing[]>("https://localhost:44324/api/Listings/");
    }
    // Edit Method
    protected async Task EditListing(int listingID)
    {
        ids = listingID.ToString();
        lsts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Listing>("https://localhost:44324/api/Listings/" + Convert.ToInt32(listingID));
    }
    // Delete Method
    protected async Task DeleteListing(int listingID)
    {
        ids = listingID.ToString();
        await Http.DeleteAsync("https://localhost:44324/api/Listings/" + Convert.ToInt32(listingID));
        listing = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Listing[]>("https://localhost:44324/api/Listings/");
    }

}
```

And here's my Controller/API:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SellEverywhere.Data;
using SellEverywhere.Models;

namespace SellEverywhere.Controllers
{   [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ListingsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ListingsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Listings
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Listing>>> GetListing()
        {
            return await _context.Listing.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Listings/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Listing>> GetListing(int id)
        {
            var listing = await _context.Listing.FindAsync(id);

            if (listing == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return listing;
        }

        // PUT: api/Listings/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutListing(int id, Listing listing)
        {
            if (id != listing.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(listing).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ListingExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Listings
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Listing>> PostListing(Listing listing)
        {
            listing.UserId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            _context.Listing.Add(listing);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetListing", new { id = listing.Id }, listing);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Listings/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Listing>> DeleteListing(int id)
        {
            var listing = await _context.Listing.FindAsync(id);
            if (listing == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Listing.Remove(listing);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return listing;
        }

        private bool ListingExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Listing.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


namespace SellEverywhere.Models
{
    public class Listing
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string Tag1 { get; set; }
        public string Tag2 { get; set; }
        public string Tag3 { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int LowestPrice { get; set; }
        public int ShippingPrice { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Photos> Photos { get; set; }
    }
    public class Photos
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("Listing")]
        public int ListingId { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public virtual Listing Listing { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the model related codes `SellEverywhere.Models` and `SellEverywhere.Data;`? Besides, I suggest you could use browser's F12 developtool see what has happened when you call the web api firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "submit" button, when executed, submits form data to the server, right ? Is this your intention? I guess not... You actually want to call the AddListing method from which you perform an HTTP Fetch API (HttpClient service) call to a Web Api end point, and not to perform the traditional post request of the form data, which does not exist in the realm of SPA applications. Thus you should use a button of the type that does not perform the post request, and instead only call your AddListing method...

Note: In the early stages of the development of Blazor, the Blazor JS code contained code that simply cancel the "submit" request.

You should use the EditForm component and the Blazor Forms components, such as InputText, etc. for tasks like yours. In that case you can use the "submit" button whose submission action is automatically cancelled by the framework.

Comment: So it works on the first try now after changing the button type to "button". I'm still interested in knowing why it would only work after the first try before. Also, why use EditForm and Blazor Form components if a regular HTML form works fine? What's the advantage/difference? Thank you!

Comment: I can't exactly say what's going on unless I see the complete code you use. However, the fact is that clicking on the "submit" button first initiates a server-side post, after which other event handlers occur. Again, this can come in many variations depending on what code you use. But what is most important to remember is that the submit button performs a server-side post, which you did not intend, and which results in the re-creating of your SPA.

Comment: " why use EditForm and Blazor Form components if a regular HTML form works fine" . You don't have  to use the built-in Input* components, unless you want to provide modification notifications, validations, and other services. These components were created to make the life of a developer easier, and allow him to focus on developing his app, instead of trying to create components and objects with functionalities provided by the built-in components.

Comment: I appreciate the info. I decided to go with the Blazor InputFile method and now I have a new question if you want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460578/how-to-bind-blazor-inputfile-to-a-one-to-many-collection-of-images

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside try catch block, sometimes it throws an exception without being noticed, or shown.